# Adding data attributes to elements not yet inserted into DOM in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, html5-canvas

So I'm basically adding some elements to the DOM on the fly.  I can use method like .addClass on them before they exist, and the class is appended to the DOM along with the element, but when I use the .data() method to add a data attribute, the data isn't appended to the DOM with the element.  Am I missing something here or do I really have to wait until the element exists in the DOM to add data to it?

PS.  Using jquery 1.9.1

[HERES A FIDDLE FOR YOU TO PLAY WITH](http://jsfiddle.net/rTfvG/2/)

**JS**

```
var widget = $("<div>");
widget.addClass("banana");
widget.data('color', 'brown');
widget.appendTo('#container');
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

And theres some nice css there so you know where to click to inspect and see the data attribute isn't(or hopefully is) added.

My expected result is

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="banana" data-color="brown"></div>
</div>
```

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure about it ? have you tried to log it ?

Comment: @RicardoLohmann when I inspect the element I don't see the data being added to it in the DOM

Comment: @RicardoLohmann but maybe thats just a weird jsfiddle quirk?

Comment: [relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr)

Comment: The `data` attr is not used to create nodes at your will. It simply corroborates the object data with the DOM. if you want to explicitly set something you have gotta use `attr` . Good Luck !

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [`.data()` method](http://api.jquery.com/data) does not create `[data-*]` attributes on DOM nodes. It simply associates the data object with the DOM node. It *does* initialize with values from `[data-*]` attributes if any exist, but this is not the same thing.

If you need to set an explicit `[data-*]` attribute value (such as a styling hook with CSS), then you need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

Comment: ah.  I see.  After reading the link you posted and this answer I see why I was confused.  I don't usually use the .data() in quite the way I'm using it here.  thanks for doing my research for me!

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work for me,

```
var widget = $("<div>");
widget.addClass("banana");
jQuery.data(widget, 'color', 'brown');
widget.appendTo('#container');
console.log(jQuery.data(widget));
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rTfvG/3/

Comment: when I inspect the element I don't see the data being added to it in the DOM still, but maybe thats a jsfiddle quirk>

Comment: @Rooster, that's not a jsFiddle quirk. The data is in the DOM but not shown in the [data-*] attribute.